# How to match the Code of barcode with array codes?

Tags: arrays, swift, string-matching

I want a matching array has codes
I've match one code it works without a problem
this code is works well

```
 let code = "code"

   if metadataObj.stringValue == code {

  println("the code is true")

    }else {

        println("the code is false") 

   }
```

But when I try this code

```
 var codes = ["a","b","c"]

   if metadataObj.stringValue == codes {
       println("the code is true")

        }else {

       println("the code is false") 
   }
```

This problem appears
cannot invoke == with an argument list of type

It works well with array var codes = ["a","b","c"] But when you put array of analysis JSON local file is not working

Comment: Checking a *string* and an *array* for equality makes  no sense. What is it that you actually want to test?

Comment: I want to check the code of barcode if found in array
array of local JSON file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *string* cannot be equal to an *array*.

If you want to test if the string is equal to one of the array elements
then use `contains()`:

```
if contains(codes, metadataObj.stringValue) { ... }
```

Comment: It works well with array var codes = ["a","b","c"]
But when you put array of analysis JSON local file is not working

Comment: @Devios: I can only provide an answer for what you write in your question.

Comment: I will modify the question and I hope to answer

Comment: @Devios: What is an "array of analysis JSON local file" ?? You have to show a concrete, reproducible example.

Comment: I have a json file Contains a set of codes Has been read successfully How are matched set of codes with code from barcode